# IPython history completion not readible

Tags: colors, ipython, completion

The history completion is not readible in my IPython terminal.

[image]

I'm using gvim (on windows, with the edge theme), and am running IPython inside a vim terminal.

I would like to the change the color used for history completion so that it becomes a bit more readible.

I tried a couple of things, including settings the colors (Linux, Neutral, etc.), setting the highlighting theme in the IPython profile (currently set to one-dark).